# Как составить текущую дату для cookie?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookie

Цель: удалить куку.
Вот такой вариант не срабатывает:

```
datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
setcookie = "Set-cookie: {0}={1}; {2}={3}".format('name','value','expires',datenow)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум, нужно [правильный формат времени (`sane-cookie-date`) для `Expires` атрибута использовать](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) :

```
>>> from email.utils import formatdate
>>> formatdate(usegmt=True)
'Sun, 08 May 2016 20:01:48 GMT'
```

Для создания cookies можно использовать [`http.cookies.SimpleCookie`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html#module-http.cookies), [пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557039/4279).