# Как удалить cookies в python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть сайт на питоне, где можно авторизоваться, после авторизации создается куки, появится кнопка выхода (при нажатии откроется отдельная страница, которая уничтожает куки и перенаправляет на главную страницу).

Код создания куки:

```
a = http.cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ.get("HTTP_COOKIE"))
name = a.get("name")
d = formatdate(localtime=True)
setc = "Set-cookie: name='value'; expires={0}".format(d)
print(setc)
```

Comment: Откуда удалить?

Comment: К примеру, создадим кнопку удаления куки. Если нажмем на него, то куки удалятся (из сервера). Пробовал ставить время 0 секунд, но не помогает, куки остаются

Comment: Во-первых, куки по определению не хранятся на сервере. Во-вторых, какое отношение питон имеет к серверу? В третьих, где какую кнопку?

Comment: Кнопка, с обработчиком, где будет код, которая уничтожает куки. 
Уточню: есть сайт на питоне, где можно авторизоваться, после авторизации создается куки, появится кнопка выхода (при нажатии откроется отдельная страница, которая уничтожает куки и перенаправляет на главную страницу)

Comment: Вот это всё и надо написать в вопросе, плюс желательно код, который создаёт куки

Comment: 1- кавычки двойными должны быть для значения cookie 2- [используйте `formatdate(usegmt=True)`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/521579/23044) (я ошибся, когда предложил `formatdate(localtime=True)` в начальной версии ответа) 3- `a.get('name')` строчка никак в коде не используется и соответственно SimpleCookie также не ясно с какой целью вызван.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Correct way to delete cookies server-side](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5285940/4279)

Answer (score 1):

Задайте ей неверное значение и установите `Expires` атрибут на дату из прошлого:

```
>>> from http.cookies import SimpleCookie
>>> ck = SimpleCookie()                                                                                  
>>> ck['name'] = 'invalid'                                                                               
>>> ck['name']['Domain'] = 'example.com'
>>> ck['name']['Path'] = '/'
>>> ck['name']['Expires'] = 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT' # from the past
>>> str(ck)
'Set-Cookie: name=invalid; Domain=example.com; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; Path=/'
```

Код предполагает, что `invalid` это неверное значение для данной cookie и поэтому не будет путаницы, даже если User-Agent проигнорирует Expires атрибут. Идея из [ответа @Lekensteyn из похожего вопроса на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5285982/4279).

Чтобы Set-Cookie имело эффект, Domain и Path должны соответствовать для соответсвующего cookie (в данном случае с именем `name`).